# Having issues with my long running task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net web app but I am unable to navigate through it while my process in the background finishes what it's doing, which is getting data from a stored procedure (takes about ~20 secs). This action gives me a Json string in return. Once it's done I am able to navigate just fine. But, my question is: what do I need to do in order to keep my website responsive while my main operation finishes?

The way my main site is set up a form in in Index.cshtml and once the page load I do a "force submit" in order to call my action.

```
@model Foo.Models.HomeViewModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="page-content">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetData", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
  HttpMethod = "post",
  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}, new { id = "MyForm" })){
<div id="status-container" class="col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <div id="red-count" class="status-box" style="background-color:#red">---</div>
<!-- More elements like these below --!>
}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$.ajax({
      url: '../Home/GetData',
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
        //give me my data
      }
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
using CVDashboard.Models;
using CVDashboard.Services;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CVDashboard.Controllers
{
  [Route("Home")]
  [Route("Home/Index")]
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    FooServices Service = new FooServices();
    HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
        {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
      model.FooCollection = Service.GetViewData(); //my stored procedure

      return Json(new { result = model.FooCollection }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: $.ajax is async by default you shouldn't have an issue there. Maybe putting that in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: Do you have `$.ajaxSetup({async: true});`? As hardkoded says it should be true by default.

Comment: @JohnWu intersting I will do more research on that. Yeah, this shouldn't be happening

Comment: @mmangual83 Just occurred to me.... does your ASP.NET web site use session variables? That could easily be the problem. See [this article](http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is either optimise your sps and code to perorm second method is instead of loading it via ajax bring the data with the view render function example

now here you should create a new viewmodel and then move but for undrstanding  i am using viewbag its not a good practice though

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
ViewBag.TheJsonWhichIsTakingTime = YourBLL.Action();
return view(model);
}
```

now in the view part

```
@section scripts
{

$(function(){
var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.TheJsonWhichIsTakingTime));
YourVewRelatedFunction(jsonData);
})

    function YourVewRelatedFunction(data)
    {
    //The Code block you used in success function of ajax
    }

}
```

Comment: I need clarification as to what is "sps"?

Comment: stored procedures

Comment: thank you. I had to do some workaround to make it work for me but it works! Though honestly I need to look deeper as to why it wasn't working before. Ajax should do it's "magic" asynchronous, so there's something else at work here... but thank you again. You deserve the points